# How to Edit Version in .aab file using Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Unity crashed right after I made a successful .aab file, I lost a lot of progress but still have this file. I cannot upload it to google play because I already have a version 1 uploaded apparently although I see it nowhere, how can I change the version in android studio if possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is possible although I do have a few suggestions for you to try out:

1. Analyze your bundle in Android Studio, find the manifest, and try changing the version code there. I don't know whether this would work considering you would need to change it in the build.gradle file ideally and you can't find this in your bundle.
2. If you are merely interesting in publishing it to see it or something along those lines, I'd recommend publishing to Internal App Sharing. It's an internal testing track but version code doesn't matter.

Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Sadly I already redid all my lost progress. Giving you answer in hopes it helps someone else.